# Как задать цвет :after у элемента?

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть скрипт выбора цвета, который задает цвет нужного элемента:

Пробовал таким образом, но что-то не пошло...

html

```
<div id="content">test</div>
```

css

```
#content:after {
  border-top-color: attr(data-after);
}
```

js

```
 if (ColorElement == '#bottom_color_form') {
    content.dataset.after = hex // пробовал так
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, вам подойдет вот такой подход.

Можно в качестве цвета бакграунда использовать переменную [currentColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword).

```js
function changeColor(el) {
  document.querySelector('.content').style.color = el.value;
}
```

```css
.content:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
<input placeholder="color" oninput="changeColor(this)">
```

Comment: окей, рабочий варинат .content:after, цвет меняется, а если у меня например есть еще и .content:before. Т.е. У меня before отвечает за фон стрелочки (должен быть в цвет выбратнного фона), а after отвечает за цвет бордера стрелочки.

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev Может, тогда отдельным вопросом оформите, а этот ответ отметите как принятый? И приведёте достаточно кода для вопроизведения вашей проблемы.

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev с `:before` все точно также можно сделать. Спокойно добавляйте `:before` и ставьте ему цвет через  `currentColor`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko тут проблема в том, что цвет у :after и :before может быть разный. как тогда быть?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev Надо с самого начала стараться давать полностью исчерпывающую информацию в вопросе. Если цвета разные, то в одном элементе сделать не получится. Можете попробовать использовать два разных элемента.

Answer (score 2):

Строго говоря, для передачи в attr() цвета (и в целом значения, отличного от content) нужно явно указывать тип - [см. MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr):

```
/* With type */
attr(src url);
attr(data-count number);
attr(data-width px);
```

В частности, там есть тип color.

Увы, возможность передавать в attr() что-то отличное от content до сих пор не поддерживается ни одним браузером - см. [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr).

[image: гистограмма с can i use]

Так что даже без JS такой вариант установки цвета работать не будет:

```css
#content:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 30px; 
  width: 30px;
  /* background-color: #FF0000; */
  background-color: attr(data-color color);
}
```

```html
<div id="content" data-color="#FF0000"></div>
```

Напрямую манипулировать псевдоэлементами из JS невозможно, так, видимо, остаётся только вариант заранее объявить классы с необходимыми цветами (и переключать их через JS):

```css
.content:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 30px; 
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.content_red:after {
  background-color: #F00;
}

.content_blue:after {
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<div class="content content_red"></div>
```