# Как изменить цвет градиента у псевдоэлемента при определенном условии?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Есть блоки, в которых верхняя градиентная верхушка реализована с помощью псевдоэлемента `before`. (изменить `html` структуру нельзя)

Как сделать так, чтобы при определенном выполнении условия менялся цвет градиента у псевдоэлемента?

Числа подгружаются с базы, они могут быть рандомные, поэтому реализовать проверку можно только на `js`

**Код:**

```js
var day = $(".day");
if (day.text() == "1") {
  //заменить цвета #fe7f40 #f4d991
} else if (day.text() == "2" || day.text() == "3") {
  //заменить цвета #187548 #0cb87d
} else if (day.text() == "4" || day.text() == "5" || day.text() == "6") {
  //заменить цвета #0b4883 #00dafa
}
else {

}
```

```css
.day {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 2px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 12%;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.day:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #f94241), color-stop(100%, #fe7f40));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f94241', endColorstr='#fe7f40', GradientType=1);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="day">1</div>
  <div class="day">2</div>
  <div class="day">3</div>
  <div class="day">4</div>
  <div class="day">5</div>
  <div class="day">6</div>
  <div class="day">7</div>
</div>
```

Есть ли способ это реализовать кроме костыля

```
$('head').append('<style>.day:after{background: linear-gradient(to right, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%) !important;}</style>');
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, к псевдоэлементам из js нельзя достучаться. Поэтому лучше всего будет менять через классы.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko пожалуйста, не отбирайте надежду у людей. Лучше посмотрите в сторону CSS-переменных: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/959767/265406

Comment: @UModeL а как обстоят дела с поддержкой от браузеров?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko весьма достойно обстоят - https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: @UModeL да, весьма достойно. Разве что в Edge 15 на псевдо-элементах работать не будет. Ну да это мелочи....

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko главное, что идёт на связке _WinXP+Chrome49_. А _Edge_ достойный продолжатель традиции _IE_ - идти своим путём. Статистика упрямая вещь - https://www.playground.ru/blogs/other/statistika_os_i_brauzerov_za_yanvar_2019_goda-336098/

Comment: @UModeL спасибо, но пока даже от IE11 нельзя отказываться, 5% пользователей на нем и ниже сидят. Думаю, очень мало заказчиков, особенно предлагающих товары и пускающие на свой сайт рекламу, готовые отказаться от такого куска пирога

Answer (score 1):

Зачем так усложнять? Пустите переменную в название класса и создайте нужные варианты стилей без js.

`<div class="day">1</div>`

Где «1» - переменная выводит информацию из БД

Измененный: `<div class="day day1">1</div>`

Добавляем необходимые стили в CSS: `day.day1 { нужные стили }`; `day.day2 { нужные стили }` и т.д.

Comment: внимательно читайте таск, я не просто так в скобочках указывал (изменить html структуру нельзя)
Если есть такое условие, значит нужно думать в рамках него и нет нужды гадать почему так, а не иначе. 
Впрочем верный ответ уже был написан внизу

Comment: @Вася я внимательно читал. В твоем случае, от добавления переменной, структура никак HTML-тэгов не меняется. Твой код: <div class="day">Вывод</div>. Измененный: <div class="dayВывод"></div>, или <div class="dayВывод">Вывод</div>, или <div class="day newclassВывод">Вывод</div>. Разве трудно переменную добавить такую же к классу? Структура не меняется.

Comment: я вас не понял, что вы писали про доп класс, но теперь посмотрите на мой ответ, который был дан раньше вашего комментария - в чем ваше новшество? и с вы на ты некорректно переходить, но так и быть плюсом вашу помощь оценю

Comment: @Вася нового в этом ничего такого нет. Просто если ты используешь переменную, в которой цифры, то логично ее пустить на доп класс и уже для нужных классов прописать конкретный градиент. Плюс в том, что не нужно использовать js, не нужно писать на js условия следовательно. Переменной и доп. классов в css достаточно, конкретные цифры - конкретный градиент. Если я оскорбил обращаясь на ТЫ, то хочу сказать, что в мыслях такого не было. Хорошо если, хотите, то на вы.

Answer (score 0):

По совету @Stepan Kasyanenko прописал стили на каждый класс

```
.day.first:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #f94241), color-stop(100%, #fe7f40));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f94241 0%, #fe7f40 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f94241', endColorstr='#fe7f40', GradientType=1);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.day.second:after{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #0b4883 0%, #00dafa 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #0b4883), color-stop(100%, #00dafa));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0b4883 0%, #00dafa 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #0b4883 0%, #00dafa 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #0b4883 0%, #00dafa 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0b4883 0%, #00dafa 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0b4883', endColorstr='#00dafa', GradientType=1);
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

И при проверке просто их добавляю в элемент:

```
if (day.text() == "1") {
day.addClass('first');
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите еще комментарий от @Umodel под вашим вопросом. Есть хороший способ. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834580/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-after-%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/959767#959767